# PHP not detect GET language from rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this multi language rewrite url from `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((fr))/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ article.php?page=$3&id=$4&title=$5$lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

in `article.php` page I need to print `fr` from `$_GET['lang']`. But i see blank and not detect `$_GET['lang']`:

```
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']);
echo $lang;
```

how do can i print lang name from rewrite url?!

Comment: You use **$** instead of **&** in your query, just befor the **lang** param. `article.php?page=$3&id=$4&title=$5&lang=$1`

Comment: Why did you wrap `fr` by double parentheses: `((fr))`?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh: you right. i need to remove double parentheses.

Comment: what it printing to you when you echo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like there is a `$` before `lang`

try

```
article.php?page=$3&id=$4&title=$5&lang=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
article.php?page=$3&id=$4&title=$5$lang=$1
```

it should be used like this

```
article.php?page=$3&id=$4&title=$5&lang=$1
```

And Also isset  Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL so it will return as true or false

```
 $lang = isset($_GET['lang']);
    echo $lang;
```

$lang contains true or false not name of lang use this like

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
 $lang = $_GET['lang'];
 echo $lang;
}
```